# Set NSWindow content view from NSViewController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, nsviewcontroller

In my App Delegate, I load the "MainView" of the `MainViewController` as follows:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    
    MainViewController *mainvc = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainView" bundle:nil];
    [self.window setContentView:mainvc.view];
}
```

Within the "MainView", I have a button connected to the following `IBAction` method:

```
- (IBAction)switchToOneView:(id)sender {
    
    OneViewController *onevc = [[OneViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OneView" bundle:nil];
    [self.view.window setContentView:onevc.view];
}
```

I want to use this button to change the content view of the main window. Unfortunately this does not work and I receive the following error:

```
[NSLock switchToOneView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000000c5b00
```

Any suggestions on how to switch the content view of a `NSWindow` with the view of a `NSViewController`?

Here's a diagram of what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

A button in the "MainView" will change the content view to "OneView" or "TwoView". Once that view is loaded, I would like to click a button in that view to remove it and return back to the "MainView".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting indicates, in most cases, a memory management bug. It means that the message `switchToOneView:` was sent to an object of class `NSLock`. Unsurprisingly, `NSLock` doesn't recognize that message.

So, to what target is the button which sends `switchToOneView:` connected? Whatever that is, it has been deallocated. Another object, an instance of `NSLock` has, by chance, been allocated at the address that used to hold the target.

I suspect the button was targeting the `MainViewController`. Since you don't continue to hold a strong reference to that controller after `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:`, ARC has fully released it, resulting in it being deallocated.

Running your app under the Zombies instrument would tell you for sure.